# Azure APIM : is there any IDE plugin for writing Azure Policy with intellisense

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am new to Azure API management. I was writing policies for our APIM. As the policy gets more complex, it seems very difficult to find exact method or way to write.

Is there any plugin like VS code plugin which will enable us to write Azure policy, or atleast C# expression part. Does any plugin has the intellisense build in for writing and evaluating Azure policy in IDE without directly putting to  Azure APIM.

Need some suggestion to find best IDE/tool to write few complex AZURE APIM policy.

Comment: this a nice feedback item, Please raise one and you will get my vote-up. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management


I have been struggling throught it too. And sometime Microsoft editor behaves strage and changes all special character to html encoded string, and hence not allowing us to save anything.

Comment: Thanks Agni, There is already one request open from a long time. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/8683888-visual-studio-integration-for-policy-editing-and-t  but didn't get appropriate votes to move forward

Answer (score 0):

There is [a snippets file for the Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets) located in a Github repository.

Unfortunately, it supports only policies structures, without autocompleting the C# expressions.